# Como pegas os elementos

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```js
const headerNavLink = document.querySelectorAll('.header-nav-link')
const headerNavItemTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.header-nav-item__title')

headerNavItemTitle.forEach(function(e, indice) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(headerNavLink[indice])
  })
})
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav">
  <ul class="header-nav-items header-nav-items--mobile">
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">CBA</span>
    </li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">Aluminio</span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title"><a href="#"
                    class="header-nav-item__link">Produtos</a></span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title"><a href="#"
                    class="header-nav-item__link">Carreiras</a></span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">Contato</span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">EN</span></li>
  </ul>

  <nav class="header-nav-content">
    <div class="header-nav-link" data-number="1">
      Data 1
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav-link" data-number="2">
      Data 2
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav-link" data-number="3">
      Data 3
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Como posso fazer para quando clicar em header-nav-item__title (CBA), header-nav-item__title (Aluminio), header-nav-item__title (contato) ter acesso aos data-number?

Comment: Qual é a relação entre `.header-nav-item__title` e `.header-nav-link`? qual o `data-number` que corresponde a cada?

Comment: De maneira linear quando clicar em CBA apareca o Data 1, quando clicar em Aluminio apareca o Data 2, e quando clicar em Contato apareca o Data3

Comment: Então queres ignorar os que têm um link como `Produtos` e `Carreiras`?

Comment: Sim quero ignorar os que tem links 'Produtos e Carreiras'.

Comment: Ok, editei a resposta, juntei um filtro para remover os `li` que têm `a` dentro.

Comment: Resolveu meu problema.. Valeu Sergio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para aceder ao atributo `data-` podes usar o [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). Um exemplo seria:

```
headerNavLink[indice].dataset.number
```

Com o teu código seria:

```js
const headerNavLink = document.querySelectorAll('.header-nav-link')
const headerNavItemTitle = [...document.querySelectorAll('.header-nav-item__title')]

headerNavItemTitle
  .filter(el => !el.querySelector('a'))
  .forEach(function(e, indice) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(headerNavLink[indice].dataset.number)
    })
  })
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav">
  <ul class="header-nav-items header-nav-items--mobile">
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">CBA</span>
    </li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">Aluminio</span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title"><a href="#"
                class="header-nav-item__link">Produtos</a></span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title"><a href="#"
                class="header-nav-item__link">Carreiras</a></span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">Contato</span></li>
    <li class="header-nav-item"><span class="header-nav-item__title">EN</span></li>
  </ul>

  <nav class="header-nav-content">
    <div class="header-nav-link" data-number="1">
      Data 1
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav-link" data-number="2">
      Data 2
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav-link" data-number="3">
      Data 3
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav-link" data-number="4">
      Data 4
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: Desculpa... a pergunta tava errada.. Ja modifiquei, se puder me ajudar lhe agradeço abraço!